# Django add field to auth_user

Tags: django, authentication, django-models

I am trying to implement the above to add a field 'posts' to the user model using the first option, extended it.

models.py

```
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class NewUserModel(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        posts = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
def site_users(request):
    site_users = User.objects.all().reverse()
    paginator = Paginator(site_users, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        users_model = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        users_model = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        users_model = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render(request, 'site_users.html', {'users_model': users_model, 'current_time':   timezone.now()})
```

But how can I get the posts field in the template, (updated, corrected and working!)

```
{% for item in users_model %}
        <tr>
          <td><a href="{% url 'profile' item.id %}">{{ item.username }}</a></td>
          <td>{{ item.newusermodel.posts }}</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

The tables in the sqlite3 DB have no User model, but it does have auth_user. Should i be using that instead of User?

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: You don't need to pass the current time in your context, it's available in templates with the [now tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#now)

Comment: @JensAstrup Thanks I didn't realise that. Cheers!

Comment: auth_user is the User model

Comment: Ok great, thanks for that clarification, I needed it.

Comment: If I use the now tag in the template would i still be able to calculate the difference between a certain date and time and now?

Comment: Have you looked at the [timesince](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) template filter? You should be able to do that with `now` as well though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`users_model` doesn't reference `NewUserModel`, it references `User`. You need to access the related model in your template like so:

```
{% for item in users_model %}
        <tr>
          <td><a href="{% url 'profile' item.id %}">{{ item.username }}</a></td>
          <td>{{ item.newusermodel.posts }}</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks but no luck with this,
<td>{{ item.new_user_model.posts }}abc</td> 
It isn't reading the field 'posts' in new_user_model. I have added that model to admin.py and there is data in it.

Comment: Tried this in my IDE and it's working out to `item.newusermodel.posts` instead of `item.new_user_model.posts`. Not sure why, I'm pretty sure I have models with CamelCase that end up with the underscores...

Comment: Editing my answer to remove the underscores - just looked at something similar in my own code and my memory added underscores where there are none, sorry!

Comment: Yes that works now, brilliant, thanks again for your help.